# For $k$-cycle $(1, 2, ..., k)$, do the elements in it need to be taken in order?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

For $k$-cycle $(1, 2, ..., k)$, do the elements in it need to be taken in order?
Is $(3,1,5,2,4)$ a $5$-cycle? Or the elements in the rotation must satisfy a law of order? i.e. $5$-cycle just are $(1,2,3,4,5)$ or $(5,4,3,2,1)$.

For $k$-cycle, do the elements in them need to be in order?

When we say "$\sigma=(i_1,i_2,...,i_k)$
, then 1) $\sigma(i_1)=i_2$, $\sigma(i_2)=i_3$, ..., $\sigma(i_k)=i_1$;   2) $\sigma(n)=n$, $n\notin\left \{i_1,i_2,...,i_k\right \}$." For $\left \{i_1,i_2,...,i_k\right \}$, them can be $\left \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\right \}$ or $\left \{1,3,2,5,4\right \}$. Is it not necessary that $i_1=1$,$i_2=2$,$\cdots$,$i_k=k$?

Comment: What’s your interpretation? Be lucid.

Comment: To effectively use the cycle notation you need to look at them long and hard. Until you understand that $(12345)$ and $(12354)$ are different permutations. But also that $$(12354)=(23541)=(35412)=(54123)=(41235).$$ They all mean the permutation that maps $1\mapsto2$, $2\mapsto 3$, $3\mapsto5$, $4\mapsto1$, $5\mapsto4$. In other words, in a cycle *the order matters*, but *the starting point does not*.

Comment: They can be in any order. Of course to express a *particular*    k-cycle one cannot re-arrange the order at random and still have the same k-cycle. However for example (1,3,2,4) and (3,2,4,1) are the same 4-cycle.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the confusion, I think I understand the concept of $k-cycle$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the same reason that a bijection does not send a particular element in its domain to its range prior to others, the specific order in cycle notation does not matter. For example, the function (bijection) $$f: \left\{1,2,3\right\}\to \left\{1,2,3\right\}$$ given by $$1 \mapsto 3 $$ $$2 \mapsto 1$$ $$3\mapsto 2$$ is *the same* function $$f: \left\{1,2,3\right\}\to \left\{1,2,3\right\}$$ given by  $$2 \mapsto 1$$ $$1 \mapsto 3 $$ $$3\mapsto 2$$ In other words the function (bijection) $f\in S_3$ can be represented equivalently by $$(1 3 2)$$ *or* $$(2 1 3).$$

Comment: Oh, thanks. When we say "$\sigma = (i_1, i_2, ..., i_k)$, then 1)  $\sigma(i_1)=i_2$, $\sigma(i_2)=i_3$, ..., $\sigma(i_k)=i_1$; 2)  $\sigma(n)=n$, $n\notin \left \{i_1, i_2, ..., i_k\right \} $." For $\left \{i_1, i_2, ..., i_k\right \} $, them can be $\left \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}$ or $\left \{1, 3, 2, 5, 4\right \} $. It is not necessary that $i_1=1, i_2=2, ... , i_k=k$.

Comment: Correct. In other words, in a set, order does not matter.

Comment: I'm truly thankful for your help.